# Get exit code when piping into grep -v

Tags: bash, grep, exit-code

I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "hello"
echo "goodbye"
exit 1
```

When I run it on its own, I get the failed exit code as I expect.

```
$ ./fail.sh
hello
goodbye
$ echo $?
1
```

However, when I run it through `grep -v`, the exit status changes to success:

```
$ ./fail.sh | grep -v hello
goodbye
$ echo $?
0
```

Is there a way to pipe a command's output into `grep -v` and still have the status code be properly propagated?  Of course in the real world the point of this would be to filter the output of a noisy command, while still detecting if the command failed.

Comment: Don't know if you can do that directly, but you can always redirect output to a tmp file, which allows you to grab the return of the initial grep and then apply your second grep to the output file contents.

Comment: limp_chimp have you had a chance to test the suggestions that @hek2mgl or I posted for you? If it works for you be sure to post feedback and consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Not sure why this was missed, but `grep -v` is a *really bad* command to use for this example. That is because although `grep` follows convention with regards to exit status, `grep -v` does not necessarily. In other words, using `-v` inverts the match but *not* the exit code. My experience is that `grep -v` returns success when it returns non-matches. If there are no non-matches to return it returns fail. If nothing matches it returns all the lines that *do not match* and success.

Comment: ^ Using `grep (GNU grep) 2.24` (`Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`) and here is a [citation](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2004-07/msg00124.html)

Comment: Use ***-L*** to get exit code for matching line that **should not be found in file**: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/534581/43233 . For example: `grep -L 'match' file | grep .`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leveraging `set -o pipefail`, the following should work:

```
( set -o pipefail; ./fail.sh | grep -v hello )
```

You can then test the value in `$?`:

```
( set -o pipefail; ./fail.sh | grep -v hello ); if [[ "$?" -eq "1" ]]; then echo success; else echo bummer; fi
```

It should output:

```
goodbye
success
```

---

**What is happening and why does this work?**

As noted in the OP, pipelines normally only return a failure (non-zero return code) if the last command errors. Using `set -o pipefail` causes a pipeline of commands to produce a failure return code if any command in the pipeline errors. The failure return code that the pipeline passes is the return code of the *last* failed command.

You can test this by updating your script to:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "hello"
echo "goodbye"
exit 5
```

then run the following:

```
( set -o pipefail; ./fail.sh | grep -v hello ); echo $?
```

It should output:

```
goodbye
5
```

The above illustrates that `set -o pipefail` is not just exiting with a non-zero return code but that it is relaying the last non-zero return code verbatim.

Comment: Sadly `pipefail` is only available on Bash, so your code fails where `sh` is Dash (e.g. Ubuntu) or where you are explicitly running your code under some particular non-Bash shell. Perhaps there's a more POSIX-compliant solution?

Comment: When answering the question, I had taken into account that the question had the BASH tag, and as such, I expected that the OP was using Bash. I am open to other suggestions that are more POSIX happy.

Answer (score 4):

`bash` will basically just give you the exit code of the last process in the pipe but you can use the `bash` specific `$PIPESTATUS` variable:

```
./fail.sh | grep -v hello
if [ ! "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" ] ; then
    echo "command has failed"
fi
```

Comment: echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}
PIPESTATUS: Undefined variable.

Comment: you need to use a modern version of bash

Comment: I don't think the process substitution approach works. It gives grep's status code, not fail's.

Comment: To get the exit code of `fail.sh`, use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` not 1

Comment: @joeytwiddle You are absolutely right. Thank you! ... (Asking me how this post has aggregated 4 upvotes over the years. It was plain wrong.. :) )